# Integral of product of zeroth-order bessel functions times cosine $\int J_{0}\left(\alpha x\right)J_{0}\left(\beta x\right)\cos(kx)\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

I am new to Bessel functions and need to solve the following integral

\begin{equation}
\int J_{0}\left(\alpha x\right)J_{0}\left(\beta x\right)\cos(kx)\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

with $J_{0}$ denothing the zeroth-order Bessel functions of the first kind, and real-valued parameters $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $k$. I already checked Wolframalpha, however without success. In Gradshteyn's book on integrals (8th edition) I only found definite integrals, which kind-of seem to be similar but have subtle (but I guess important) differences. E.g.

[6.672.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRTv7.png): however, this integral involves a sine instead of a cosine and there are a particular restrictions on the involved parameters $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $k$

[6.672.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LloHd.png): however, it is considered only for $\alpha=\beta=1$, and $k$ for a particular range

[6.676.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPU9u.png): this seem to be close to my integral of interest, except for the argument considering $\sqrt{x}$ instead of $x$

Do you know some strategies how to obtain the solution to my indefinite integral? Else, do you know how to transform the result from [6.676.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPU9u.png) so that it considers the argument as a function of $x$ and not as a function of $\sqrt{x}$? Your help is appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: Thank you very much for this great and quick response! Do you also know how to handle the intgral if the conditions for the involved parameters are not met?

Comment: The ones cited are definite integrals $\int_0^\infty$.  Answers for that case are more likely than the indefinite integral in the question.

Comment: Note that for $\beta=\alpha$, $\int_0^\infty J_0(\alpha x)J_0(\beta x)\cos(kx)=\frac{2}{k\pi}K(1-4 \alpha^2/k^2)$, with complete elliptic integral of the first kind $K$.

Comment: @FredHucht: thank you very much for this identity. Can you provide me a reference for this?

Comment: Mathematica can do it: Integrate[BesselJ[0, a x]^2 Cos[k x], {x, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> a > k/2 > 0]

Comment: nice, thank you!