# Integral of nested trigonometric function $\frac{\cos\left(p\cos\left(x\right)\right)}{p\cos\left(x\right) + c}$

Tags: integration, bessel-functions, trigonometric-functions

while still working on my problem [$\int J_{0}\left(\alpha x\right)J_{0}\left(\beta x\right)\cos(kx)\,\mathrm{d}x$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462443/integral-of-product-of-zeroth-order-bessel-functions-times-cosine-int-j-0-le) I came across the following definite integral

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos\left(p\cos\left(x\right)\right)}{p\cos\left(x\right) + c}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

with $x$ denototing a real-valued variable and $p$ and $c$ denototing real valued parameters. Unfortunately I don't have a clue how to approach this integral. WolframAlpha failed on this one and in standard integral table books like Gradshteyn and Prudnikov I could not find anything similar to my problem. Although in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546784/what-is-sin-cosx there are interesting definite integrals listed, i.e.,

[image]

I don't have the feeling that these relations are of help. Do you know how to tackle this integral or know any literature ?

As always, thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: What does "tackle the integral" mean in your context? What would you consider a satisfactory answer?

Comment: If the result of the integral could be expressed in terms of Bessel functions or special functions (e.g., generalized hypergeometric functions, elliptic integrals, ...) I would be happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that the numerator can be integrated as Bessel function with Mathematica,
$$ \tag{1}\label{eq:1}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos\left(p\cos x \right)\,\mathrm{d}x
= \pi J_0(|p|) \, .
$$
The OPs full integrand $f(x)$ can be expanded in $p$,
\begin{align}\tag{2a}\label{eq:2a}
f(x)&= \frac{\cos\left(p\cos x\right)}{p\cos x + c} \\
\tag{2b}\label{eq:2b}
&=\frac{1}{2c}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-c^{-1}\cos x)^k
\left[
 e^{ ic}\,\Gamma(k+1, ic)
+e^{-ic}\,\Gamma(k+1,-ic)
\right]  \frac{p^k}{k!} \,
\end{align}
and termwise integration yields the fast converging series ($k=2m$)
$$\tag{3}\label{eq:3}
I = \pi\sum_{m=0}^\infty
\frac{
e^{ ic} \, \Gamma(2m+1, ic) +
e^{-ic} \, \Gamma(2m+1,-ic)
}{(2c)^{2m+1} \, \Gamma (m+1)^2} \, p^{2m} \, .
$$
Another option is to write the incomplete gamma function in \eqref{eq:3} as integral,
$$\tag{3a}\label{eq:3a}
\Gamma (2m+1,z)=\int_z^{\infty} dt \, t^{2m} e^{-t}\,,
$$
and exchange sum and integral to get
$$\tag{4}\label{eq:4}
I= \frac{\pi}{2c} \int_0^\infty dt\,e^{-t} \left[
J_0\big(p(1+\tfrac{it}{c})\big) +
J_0\big(p(1-\tfrac{it}{c})\big)\right] \, .
$$

Comment: Wow, this looks great, but unfortunately I did not understand your answer. Could you elaborate on the following:
- I don't see how the incomplete Gamma function comes into play. What happens between (2a) and (2b)? What expansion is this?
- I could not follow the reasoning which led to (4). Could you provide more details? Do you claim/show that

$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos\left(p\cos\left(x\right)\right)}{p\cos\left(x\right) + c}\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2c} \int_0^\infty e^{-t} \left[
J_0\big(p(1+\tfrac{it}{c})\big) +
J_0\big(p(1-\tfrac{it}{c})\big)\right]$?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Eq. (2b) is the series expansion of (2a) in $p$ around $p=0$, done with MMA's `SeriesCoefficient[f[x], {p, 0, k}]`. Integrating termwise, only the even $k$ survive, so we set $k=2m$. Finally, the incomplete gamma function is defined as $\Gamma (a,z)=\int_z^{\infty} dt \, t^{a-1} e^{-t}$, inserting this into (3) and exchanging sum and integral gives (4).

Comment: got it, thank you a alot

Answer (score 1):

Using
$$
\frac{1}{1-2 q \cos x+q^2}=\frac{1}{1-q^2}\left(1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty q^n\cos(nx)\right),\quad |q|<1,
$$
and the integral representation https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9.E2 for Bessel coefficients
$$
J_{n}\left(z\right)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos\left(z\sin\theta-n\theta%
\right)d\theta=\frac{i^{-n}}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{iz\cos\theta}\cos%
\left(n\theta\right)d\theta,
$$
one finds
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos\left(p\cos x\right)}{1-2 q \cos x+q^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{1-q^2}\left(J_0(p)+2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n  J_{2 n}(p)q^{2 n}\right),\quad |q|<1.
\end{equation}